# Parse GeoPoint queries not working in PushQuery in android SDK

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to send geofenced notifications from device itself. This is my code.

```
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereNear("currentLoc", parseGeoPoint);

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
push.setMessage("geo push");
push.sendInBackground();
```

I have added the currentLoc and testText attributes from a service and it is showing up in parse console. The code is as follows.

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("currentLoc", parseGeoPoint);
installation.put("testText", "text");
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Now, if I use `pushQuery.whereEqualTo("testText", "texto");` instead of `pushQuery.whereNear("currentLoc", parseGeoPoint);` in the query, notifications are triggered.

But when used with `whereWithin` or `whereNear` queries, it fails and parse push console produces following error

```
ERROR:
Unable to execute query: error processing query:     ns=appdata1109.app_ded5349f-37a1-4227-a4cc-62eccd9f8a07:_Installation limit=0 skip=0 Tree: GEONEAR field=currentLoc maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=1 Sort: {} Proj: {} planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this using `whereWithinMiles`

> there is no need to extra field `location` in `installation` class you
>   can use inner query and fetch location from `User`

```
// Find users near a given location
ParseQuery userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.whereWithinMiles("location", stadiumLocation, 1.0) //1.0 is radius in miles

// Find devices associated with these users
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereMatchesQuery("user", userQuery);

// Send push notification to query
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
push.setMessage("Free hotdogs at the Parse concession stand!");
push.sendInBackground();
```